# Duplicated record TableView on javafx

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, duplicates, tableview, observablelist

I have this TableView with this configuration:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Budget> budgetTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Budget, String> idColumn, budgetNameColumn, buildingColumn, addressColumn, taxableColumn,
        budgetTotalColumn, budgetStateColumn, clientColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Budget, LocalDate> budgetDateColumn;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    ...
    clientColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Budget, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Budget, String> data) {
            if (data.getValue().getClient() != null) {
                return data.getValue().getClient().nameProperty().concat(" ")
                        .concat(data.getValue().getClient().surnameProperty());
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

1. When the app starts, the table works fine.
2. I have the problem when I try to add a new budget. I store it well in the database, but I have a NullPointerException when returning to the main view.
3. If I take control of this exception like the code shows, I have to records for the same new created budget.
4. When I create a new budget, I delete all the elements of the observable list and I fill it again as the same way of the first (that works fine).
5. In the following image, the two last records are bad records. It would just show the first and the second one.

[image]

Could anyone help me??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using a custom `cellFactory`, as well as the `cellValueFactory` you show?

Comment: I'm not using a cellFactory, I just set the column like the code shows.

Answer (score 0):

For the `null` case, return an empty `StringProperty`.

```
clientColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Budget, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Budget, String> data) {
        if (data.getValue().getClient() != null) {
            return data.getValue().getClient().nameProperty().concat(" ")
                    .concat(data.getValue().getClient().surnameProperty());
        }
        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("");
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, It has the same behavior. When I create a new budget, when I return to the main view, it shows two records for the new one, one with the client and another one without it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a "solution" for working. I don't really know why it is working like that but at this moment it works like:

```
clientColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Budget, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Budget, String> data) {
        if (data.getValue().getClient() != null) {
            return data.getValue().getClient().nameProperty().concat(" ")
                .concat(data.getValue().getClient().surnameProperty());
        } else {
            budgetList.remove(data.getValue());
        }
        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("");
    }
});
```

I just delete the null element from the observableList :)

Comment: That sounds like you have some other bug in your code that is not related to this cell value factory: you're probably going to run into problems unless you fix it.

Comment: Probably but I don't find it... May be it will appear in some other related thing... I'll tell you! Thanks